# Using CSV.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC without quoting the headers

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I don't think this question has been asked before so I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction.

I'll keep it short and sweet, Is it possible to only quote the column values and keep the column headers unquoted when using `CSV.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`?

```
docs.to_csv("test.csv", index = False, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Actual Output:

```
"id","reportname"
1,"TestReport"
```

Expected Output:

```
id,reportname
1,"TestReport"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not found such feature in [to_csv docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), thus I suggest following procedure:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1],"reportname":["TestReport"]})
df[:0].to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
df.to_csv("test.csv", header=False, mode="a", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

content of `test.csv`

```
id,reportname
1,"TestReport"
```

Explanation: First `to_csv` is used to write headers, second to write content, thus in second I specify that no header should be written (`header=False`) and it should append (`mode="a"`) rather than write new file (`w` - default mode).

Comment: That is actually a really smart way to go about it, thanks for that!